# PHP code for database connection from Android Studio

Tags: php, android, database

I am trying to connect database from Android Studio so I used PHP script.

However, the login function doesn't work. I think something wrong at the "mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)"

This is my php code:

```
<?php

  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "[username]", "[password]", "[database name]");

  $userID = $_POST["userID"];
  $userPassword = $_POST["userPassword"];

  $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE userID = ? AND userPassword  =  ?");
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $userID, $userPassword);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

  mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $userPassword, $userName, $userAge);

  $response = array();
  $response["success"] = false;

  while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement))
  {
    $response["success"] = true;
    $response["userID"] = $userID;
    $response["userPassword"] = $userPassword;
    $response["userName"] = $userName;
    $response["userAge"] = $userAge;
  }
  echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

I cannot go into the while loop. How can I fix it?

Comment: I would start with adding some error checking. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php Are you sure your connected or your select worked?

Comment: I success to connect database for registration but the login part didn't work.

Comment: I added the error check

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

There is no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The first thing to do here is to check if the connection is
   successful. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php
2. And then check whether your statement actually fetches any results using phpmyadmin or mysql console. The reason why it doesn't enter the
   loop is that `mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)` returns false at the
   moment. Perhaps, the reason could be because your password is hashed.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
When I used the sample code that you gave the link, it could fetch all the information but if I use my code it couldn't fetch any data. I can use the right code but I am still wondering which part was wrong for my code.